Rear derailleur won't shift into easiest gears
I recently bought a used bike with a SRAM Force 1x drivetrain. The bike came with a medium-cage Force 11 speed rear derailleur and a fairly small cassette (SRAM PG-1130, 11-36t). I wanted easier gears for climbing, and my old bike had a SRAM Force long cage derailleur (also 11 speed) and larger cassette (SRAM PG-1130, 11-42t), so I swapped the derailleur and cassette from my old bike on to the new bike. I also swapped the chain (new as of a few weeks ago) from my old bike on to the new bike (after re-sizing it).
After making the swap, I haven't been able to get the rear derailleur (old derailleur on the new bike) to index properly. I can get smooth shifting up until the two largest cogs on the cassette, but then it refuses to shift inboard any more. I can get it to shift onto the largest cogs by increasing the cable tension a bunch, but then it won't shift back down into the higher gears correctly. The confusing bit is that both bikes, old and new/used, were shifting fine before I made the swap, which would seem to rule out the usual suspects (bent derailleur hanger, worn out cable, etc.). Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be going on?
